# How can I get all SciPy distributions with support ranging from at most zero to infinity?

Tags: python, scipy

I'm trying to implement a code that gets a list of all the probability distributions in SciPy subject to the following criteria: a) the distribution is continuous, b) the lower bound of the support of the distribution is at most 0, and c) the upper bound of the distribution is infinity.

Is there a quick way to implement this? Maybe a way to pull the list of all *rv_continuous* distributions and then a lambda function on the distribution's support? What would it look like? Looking up all the continuous distributions on the SciPy site and taking those with the desired support is cumbersome and could be problematic if distributions are renamed, added to or removed from SciPy (I'm trying to make my code as dynamic as possible).

Thank you for your kind assistance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
all_dist = [getattr(stats, d) for d in dir(stats) if isinstance(getattr(stats, d), stats.rv_continuous)]
    filtered = [x for x in all_dist if ((x.a <= 0) & (x.b == math.inf))]
```